# Coping arrays in JAVA

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have two arrays: "newArray" and "oldArray". I have three methods: methodA, methodB and methodC. At methodA I assign oldArrays values and call methodB.

```
void methodA(){
     oldArray = {"element1", "element2", "element3"};
     methodB(oldArray); 
}
```

At methodB I initialize newArray and copy every element of oldArray to it.

```
void methodB(String[] array){
    newArray = new String[array.length];
    System.arraycopy(array, 0, newArray, 0, array.length);
}
```

And then I call methodC to print the values of newArray:

```
void methodC(){
    for(String element : newArray){
        System.out.println(element + "\n");
    }
}
```

When I try to run I get NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of a null array.

Some explanations would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Where are you calling methodC . If its in methodB are you passing your array to methodC. Please provide some code example of sequence of method calls.

Comment: What line does the exception occur on

Comment: I am not passing any parameter to methodC since the newArray is global.

Comment: Exception occurs at methodC since it cannot print anything because it can not get the length of the neeArray. It recognises it as a null array which is weird since I already gave values to it at methodB.

Answer (score 1):

Try this method

```
public static int[] copyOf(int[] original,int newLength)
```

Where:

original -- This is the array to be copied.

newLength -- This is the length of the copy to be returned.

In your case:

```
void methodB(String[] array){
newArray.copyOf(array, array.size()); }
```

But it would be better if you provide more information, like copy the error log to know in which method you get the null pointer exception

Comment: Thanks for the alternative. I'll try it out.

Answer (score 0):

In the following code snippet -

```
void methodC(){
    for(String element : newArray){
        System.out.println(element + "\n");
    }
}
```

What is `newArray`? It should be the parameter of the function, I guess.

Comment: newArray is global so I do not need a parameter for it to access.

Comment: @GabrielKuka yes, if `newArray` is global, you don't need a parameter to access.